# SAS/Oracle SQL DATEPART() with one argument

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, sas

I am converting some Oracle SQL (From an antiquated SAS environment) queries to PostgreSQL. Before I can figure out what exactly the PostgreSQL equivalent to DATEPART() and how it works is, I need to find out what the Oracle query is doing to better understand it. In a select statement, I have two parts of the query which look very similar to one another.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
/*...*/
DHMS(DATEPART(a.process_date),0,0,0) FORMAT datetime20. AS Pic_Proc_Dt,
/*...*/
DHMS(DATEPART(b.process_date),0,0,0) FORMAT datetime20. AS RESP_Proc_Dt,
/*...*/
```

In particular, I don't understand Oracle's use of the DATEPART call with only one argument. All of the resources I can find online say that you need to use two arguments in DATEPART to make it work, but this is only taking one, and this code has been running for close to 8 years.

Because I am not authorized to see the Oracle database and data inside of it, I can't make any small selections on the related table to see what exactly the data in that column looks like. But, that aside, the DATEPART function should still be taking two arguments.

What would DATEPART(arg) return, if there was only one parameter/argument sent to it?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't even know Oracle had a `datepart` function... When I try to run it, it says `invalid identifier`.

Comment: @sstan Could it be a SAS proc sql function then? It's referencing an Oracle database either way, which I don't understand.

Comment: I don't know.  Are you able to connect directly to the database using the same credentials that are used for the above query, maybe using `SQL*PLUS`?  If so, can you try running `select datepart(sysdate) from dual` and see if you actually get results, or at least, a different error?

Comment: This is SAS code, not Oracle code.  You're posting too many small questions here that you should be doing some research for before coming here.  A quick look into the SAS function documentation will answer this question.

Comment: DHMS and Datepart are both SAS functions. Check the SAS documentation for each. In general for a PROC SQL if you don't see an explicit ODBC connection it's going to be SAS function not Oracle functions.

Comment: @sstan Unfortunately not. I need a VPN to access that particular database, and I don't have the credentials to get into the VPN. It's just being converted from one script to another.

Comment: @Reeza Gotcha. That would probably explain it.

Comment: What version of SAS is considered antiquated?

Comment: Also, line to line/proc to proc conversion is a horrible way to convert code.

Comment: @Reeza I don't know what version it is, and I don't know how I'd find out. The scripts that are being converted are anywhere from 2-9 years old, most of which are closer to 7-9 years old. Given the company's history of software updates, I'd imagine this is the same version now as it was back then. And it may be a bad way to convert the code, but it's what I and my colleagues are being told to do.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a sas function. The sas datepart takes only one parameter. 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0rttbu7w62xgzn1damccyuwpld8.htm